# Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.URL_to_Corrective_Action__c'

Tags: visualforce, email-template, vf-email-template

I am receiving this error when trying to add a field to a VF template.  Here is what my code looks like:

Item Reference: {!relatedto.Corrective_Actions__r.URL_to_Corrective_Action__c}

The field I am trying to pull is not from the object the template is built on.  Because it's a URL, is there special code I need to put around it?  Sorry if the question is basic, I do not code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

__r, in reference to child records, is a list. You need to specify which record you want to use, such as the zeroth element:

```
{!relatedto.Corrective_Actions__r[0].URL_to_Corrective_Action__c}
```

Comment: Apologies, whar does the 0 represent?

Comment: @SalesforceJunkie the first record in the list (the zeroth element). Lists start from index 0 and count up.